# How to run Google Cloud SQL only when I need it?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Google Cloud SQL advertises that it's only $0.0150 per hour for the smallest machine type, and I'm being charged for every hour, not just hours that I'm connected.  Is this because I'm using a pool?  How do I setup my backend so that it queries the cloud db only when needed so I don't get charged for every hour of the day?

```
const mysql      = require('mysql');
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host : process.env.SQL_IP,
    user     : 'root',
    password : process.env.SQL_PASS,
    database : 'mydb',
    ssl      : {
          [redacted]
    }
});

function query(queryStatement, cB){
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    // Use the connection
    connection.query(queryStatement, function (error, results, fields) {
      // And done with the connection.
      connection.destroy();
      // Callback
      cB(error,results,fields);

    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not so much about the pool as it is about the nature of Cloud SQL. Unlike App Engine, Cloud SQL instances are *always* up. I learned this the hard way one Saturday morning when I'd been away from the project for a week. :)

There's no way to spin them down when they're not being used, unless you explicitly go stop the service.

There's no way to *schedule* a service stop, at least within the GCP SDK. You could alway write a cron job, or something like that, that runs a little `gcloud sql instances patch [INSTANCE_NAME] --activation-policy NEVER` command at, for example, 6pm local time, M-F. I was too lazy to do that, so I just set a calendar reminder for myself to shut down my instance at the end of my workday.

Here's the MySQL Instance start/stop/restart page for the current SDK's docs:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/start-stop-restart-instance

On an additional note, there is an ongoing '[Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/69109113)' in the GCP Platform to start/stop the Cloud SQL (2nd Gen), according to the traffic as well. You can also visit the [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/69109113) and provide your valuable suggestions/comments there as well.

Comment: sorry where would you write such a cron job which has access to gcloud?

Comment: @AlexanderShubert you can run cron on linux VM on GCP. VMs can be easily scheduled to start and stop using cloud-functions, pubsub, and scheduler in GCP

Answer (score 8):

I took the idea from @ingernet and created a cloud function which starts/stops the CloudSQL instance when needed. It can be triggered via a scheduled job so you can define when the instance goes up or down.

The details are here in this [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/lovromazgon/5074bc39b479841c83a78fcd83162eb2) (inspiration taken from [here](https://github.com/chris32g/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Cloud%20Functions/turn_off_CloudSQL_instance)). *Disclaimer:* I'm not a python developer so there might be issues in the code, but at the end it works.

---

Basically you need to follow these steps:

1. Create a pub/sub topic which will be used to trigger the cloud function.
2. [Create the cloud function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-python#create_a_function) and copy in the code below.

   1. Make sure to set the correct project ID in line 8.
   2. Set the trigger to Pub/Sub and choose the topic created in step 1.
3. [Create a cloud scheduler job](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart#create_a_job) to trigger the cloud function on a regular basis.

   1. Choose the frequency when you want the cloud function to be triggered.
   2. Set the target to Pub/Sub and define the topic created in step 1.
   3. The payload should be set to `start [CloudSQL instance name]` or `stop [CloudSQL instance name]` to start or stop the specified instance (e.g. `start my_cloudsql_instance` will start the CloudSQL instance with the name `my_cloudsql_instance`)

Main.py:

```python
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
import base64
from pprint import pprint

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = discovery.build('sqladmin', 'v1beta4', credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False)
project = 'INSERT PROJECT_ID HERE'

def start_stop(event, context):
  print(event)
  pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
  print(pubsub_message)
  command, instance_name = pubsub_message.split(' ', 1)

  if command == 'start':
    start(instance_name)
  elif command == 'stop':
    stop(instance_name)
  else:
    print("unknown command " + command)

def start(instance_name):
  print("starting " + instance_name)
  patch(instance_name, "ALWAYS")

def stop(instance_name):
  print("stopping " + instance_name)
  patch(instance_name, "NEVER")

def patch(instance, activation_policy):
  request = service.instances().get(project=project, instance=instance)
  response = request.execute()

  dbinstancebody = {
    "settings": {
      "settingsVersion": response["settings"]["settingsVersion"],
      "activationPolicy": activation_policy
    }
  }

  request = service.instances().patch(
    project=project,
    instance=instance,
    body=dbinstancebody)
  response = request.execute()
  pprint(response)
```

Requirements.txt

```
google-api-python-client==1.10.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.4
google-auth==1.19.2
oauth2client==4.1.3
```

Comment: nice work! i'll be interested to try this out in my sandbox.