# Schedule Start/stop on GCP SQL Instance

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I want to schedule my SQL Instance of GCP.
How to Trigger start/ stop SQL Instance automatically?

I already successfully scheduled the compute Engine VM but stuck in SQL Instance scheduling.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Google Cloud SQL only when I need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547016/how-to-run-google-cloud-sql-only-when-i-need-it)

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve this you can use a [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-python) to make a call to the [Cloud SQL Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/) to start and stop your Cloud SQL instance (you will need 2 Cloud functions)

```
def hello_world(request):

instance = 'test'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.
request = service.instances().get(project=project, instance=instance)
response = request.execute()
j = response["settings"]
settingsVersion = int(j["settingsVersion"])

dbinstancebody = {
   "settings": {
       "settingsVersion": settingsVersion,
       "tier": "db-n1-standard-1",
       "activationPolicy": "Always"
   }
}

request = service.instances().update(
   project=project,
   instance=instance,
   body=dbinstancebody)
response = request.execute()
pprint(response)

request_json = request.get_json()

if request.args and 'message' in request.args:
    return request.args.get('message')
elif request_json and 'message' in request_json:
    return request_json['message']
else:
    return f"Hello World!"
```

---

```
requirements.txt

google-api-python-client==1.7.8
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-auth==1.6.2
oauth2client==4.1.3
```

You can see my code on how to use a Cloud Function to [start a Cloud SQL instance](https://github.com/chris32g/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Cloud%20Functions/turn_on_cloudSQL_instance) and [stop a Cloud SQL instance](https://github.com/chris32g/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Cloud%20Functions/turn_off_CloudSQL_instance)

After creating your Cloud Function you can [configure the Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart) to trigger the HTTP address of each Cloud function or you can follow the recommended approach of this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule) and trigger the functions with pub/sub

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, Im getting this error trying your solution: "HttpError 400 when requesting... Invalid request: Only custom machine instance type and shared-core instance type allowed for PostgreSQL database."

Answer (score 1):

You can manage the start and stop operations of a Google Cloud SQL instance using the GCP REST API and Cloud Scheduler, follow the steps below:

1. Create a Service Account (SA) with the "Cloud Editor" role for Cloud Scheduler Authentication
2. Create a Cloud Scheduler:

   - **Name:** stop-start-sql
   - **Region:** europe-west-3
   - **Frequency:** 0 23 * * * (At 11:00 PM)
   - **TimeZone:** India
   - **Target Type:** HTTP
   - **URL:** https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/YOURPROJECTNAME/instances/YOURSQLINSTANCENAME
   - **Body:**

     - To start SQL, use the following JSON:

       ```json
       {
           "settings": {
               "activationPolicy": "ALWAYS"
           }
       }
       ```
     - To stop SQL, use the following JSON:

       ```json
       {
           "settings": {
               "activationPolicy": "NEVER"
           }
       }
       ```
   - **Auth Header:** Add OAuth token
   - **Service Account:** "Select your SA with cloud editor role"

This configuration allows you to use Cloud Scheduler to trigger the specified SQL instance's start and stop operations using the provided JSON payloads. The associated Service Account ensures the required permissions for authentication.